# Cannot render partial when merging data into locals in Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to refactor this haml:

```
= render 'graph_stats_portrait', item_title:       "Users",
                      chart_color:      "#fd6a2f",
                      chart_bg_color:   "#ffffff",
                      circle_color:     "orange",
                      total:            @user_data[:total],
                      by_date:          @user_data[:by_date],
                      total_today:      @user_data[:total_today],
                      total_this_week:  @user_data[:total_this_week],
                      total_this_month: @user_data[:total_this_month],
                      total_yesterday:  @user_data[:total_yesterday],
                      total_last_week:  @user_data[:total_last_week],
                      total_last_month: @user_data[:total_last_month]
```

To this:

```
= render 'graph_stats_portrait',{
  item_title:       "Users",
  chart_color:      "#fd6a2f",
  chart_bg_color:   "#ffffff",
  circle_color:     "orange"
  }.merge(@user_data)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
app/views/admin/dashboard/index.html.haml:6: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting =>
...erge(@user_data)\n", 0, false);end;_hamlout.buffer << _hamlo...
...
```

Line 6 is this:

```
item_title:       "Users",
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vitaly deserves credit for pointing me in the right direction and he is correct that this should probably be in a helper or decorator.

But....

This is what fixed the issue of this question:

```
= render 'graph_stats_portrait',
  { item_title:       "Users",
  chart_color:      "#fd6a2f",
  chart_bg_color:   "#ffffff",
  circle_color:     "orange"}.merge(@user_data)
```

Notice that every line ends in a comma (except the last).

I moved the `{` down to the next line and the `}.merge(@user_data)` up a level.

This allows Haml to read it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

"you are doing it wrong (tm)" ;)

your haml files should never have stuff like this. move it into a helper or decorator.

remember, HAML is not a full featured Ruby parser, it can't always figure out your code continues on the next line. To hint that it does you can end your line with `|`:

See http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-multiline